# Barebones Facebook Connection with flashbuilder 4.5 (mobile app)

Tags: facebook, actionscript, mobile

I am looking for a barebones facebook connection from pure actionscript to use in a mobile.  Does anyone know of any examples.  Been having a hard time finding what I want in Google

Thanks!

Comment: Then look somewhere else, because StackOverflow is not for lookers, its for people who need help in coding and related things. We are not code lenders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant connect to facebook with only actionscript - flash does not implement OAuth which you need to get a valid access token.
You have to either get an access token through PHP, or Javascript.
If you are making a mobile web-app you can check out 
http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/04/facebook-now-with-oauth-and-open-graph/

Jozef Chúťka put together a great walkthrough and classes for AS3 and facebook. 
So you can make a web app or use a web view in AIR to handle your authentication.

Comment: I got it figured out and I am not sure you are right about that.   You may be right.  I know actionsript doesn't connect directly, but it can pull in the session from your mobile device and work fine... so technically it is all with actionscript.  It just opens your mobile browser for a bit to authorize the app

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I will accept your answer for the awesome resource!

Comment: Adam: Thanks for the accept - would you mind posting how you get the session from the mobile browser?